# Which folders need to be backed up for migration in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, migration, backups

I'm helping someone update & migrate their old website, built on the Joomla framework.
Currently it is running on Joomla 1.5.8 which is an ancient version. I've convinced them to upgrade Joomla to at least 2.5

I have already made a backup of the database.

Most links I have seen talk of backing up the entire `public_html` folder (The website runs on a shared host). But in my fresh Joomla installation there are several folders that are in the `public_html` folder.

So which of the folders in the `public_html` folder are from the content of the website, and which are of the old Joomla framework?

I'm afraid that I might overwrite files of the new Joomla framework with the old framework, if copy all the files and folders into the new installation.

Comment: If you don't get an answer, you might ask over here:
http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla

Answer (score 2):

### Backup

First, make a backup of the **entire** site, best using [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html).

### Migrate

There are some tools out there to (partly) automat the migration process. You might want to have a closer look at two of them:

1. [jUpgrade](http://redcomponent.com/redcomponent/jupgrade)
2. [SPUpgrade](http://cyend.com/extensions/extensions/components/5-upgrade-joomla-from-15-to-16)

Answer (score 2):

You can find the core Joomla 1.5 file structure at: https://github.com/PhilETaylor/Joomla1.5.999

When migrating to a new version of Joomla, I usually create the `/new` sub-folder and create the new website in here. Once the new website is ready to go live, it is quite simple to move everything in the root folder except `/new` into `/old` and then move everything in `/new` to the root folder (use cPanel or similar so the move happens quickly on the server rather than via your local machine).

When moving Joomla websites between folders, you will need to update the logs and `tmp` path in Global Configuration (or edit the *configuration.php* file). If the `$live_site` parameter is set, you will also need to update this in the *configuration.php* file. Also check the *.htaccess* file (if used) for any absolute paths.